# sending array with message queue

Tags: c, xcode, ipc, message-queue

i have been trying to send an array with message queues in c. It works with a normal string, but I don´t know how to do it with an array. this is my code so far with the string attempt. Do I need to seperate the writer and receiver? I also need to send the array two more times, but I can´t start before it sends the first time.
thanks for any help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>

#define maxArr 100

//create buffer
struct msgbuffer{
    long msgtype;
    char msgtext [100];
    int arr[maxArr];
}msg;

int main(int argc , char ** argv){
    //needed variables
    int returncode_msgget;
    int returncode_msgrcv;
    int i;
    
    //create message queue
    returncode_msgget = msgget(1234, IPC_CREAT |0600);
    
    //generating random numbers
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        msg.arr[i] = rand() %101;
        printf("%d,", msg.arr[i]);
    }
    //sending message
    msg.msgtype = 1;
    strcpy(msg.msgtext,"test");
    
    //checking if message was sent
    if (msgsnd(returncode_msgget, &msg, sizeof(msg.msgtext), 0) == -1){
        printf("message not sent\n");
        perror("msgsnd()");
    }
    //buffer for message receiver
    wait(NULL);
    struct msgbuffer{
        long mtype;
        char mtext [100];
    } msg;
    
    // reaching message queue
    //checking if message queue is reachable
    msg.mtype = 1;
    if ((returncode_msgget = msgget(1234, IPC_CREAT| 0600)) < 0) {
        printf("could not reach Message queue\n");
        perror("msgget()");
    }
    //checking if message was received
    returncode_msgrcv = msgrcv(returncode_msgget, &msg, sizeof(msg.mtext), msg.mtype, MSG_NOERROR|IPC_NOWAIT);
    if (returncode_msgrcv == -1) {
        printf("message not received\n");
        perror("msgrcv()");
        
    //if message received, notification
    }else {
         printf ("Diese Nachricht wurde aus der Warteschlange gelesen : %s \n" , msg . mtext );
         printf ("Die empfangene Nachricht ist %i Zeichen lang .\n" , returncode_msgrcv );
         }
    printf("test");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this was my attempt for sending an array which I saw on another post here:

```
 //checking if message was sent
    if (msgsnd(returncode_msgget, (int*) &msg.arr[i], sizeof(msg.arr[i]), 0) == -1){
        printf("message not sent\n");
        perror("msgsnd()");
    }
```

Comment: So does this answer solve your problem? If so, how? If not, then it should not be posted as an answer, but as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72650800/edit) to the question, detailing your attempt. Preferably as a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).